# Learning rate for lightgbm with boosting_type = "rf"

Tags: python, random-forest, lightgbm

In the documentation i could not find anything on if/how the learning_rate parameter is used with random forest as boosting type in the python lightgbm implementation:
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html -- Intuitively it makes sense to set the learning rate to 1 because there is no iterative approximation of the loss functions gradient with this "boosting" type.

In this example, the learning rate is also actually set to 1:
https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/691

However in other exapmles i found all over the internet it is not and i haven't seen anybody point this out as a mistake.

**What is the python lightgbm implementation (https://pypi.org/project/lightgbm/) actually doing with the learning rate parameter when boosting_type = "rf"?**

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same question: As expected changing the learning rate had no empirical effects with lightgbm in random forest mode.